# Printing list items by group in python

Tags: python

I'm still new to Python. I have similar list to the below list:

`items = [[4, 'A'], [4, 'B'], [5, 'C'], [5, 'D'], [5, 'E'], [6, 'F'], [6, 'G']]`

I'm trying to print it by grouping the first item together and get something like this:

```
4 : ['A', 'B']
5 : ['C', 'D', 'E']
6 : ['F', 'G']
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list_ = [[4, 'A'], [4, 'B'], [5, 'C'], [5, 'D'], [5, 'E'], [6, 'F'], [6, 'G']]
>>> print(*(f'{k}: {sum(list(g), [])}' 
            for k, g in groupby(list_, key=lambda x: list.pop(x, 0))), 
           sep='\n')
4: ['A', 'B']
5: ['C', 'D', 'E']
6: ['F', 'G']
```

If you want to do this without importing anything:

```
>>> list_ = [[4, 'A'], [4, 'B'], [5, 'C'], [5, 'D'], [5, 'E'], [6, 'F'], [6, 'G']]

>>> table = {}

>>> for key, value in list_:
        table.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
    

>>> table
{4: ['A', 'B'], 5: ['C', 'D', 'E'], 6: ['F', 'G']}

>>> for key, group in table.items():
        print(f'{key}: {group}')
    
4: ['A', 'B']
5: ['C', 'D', 'E']
6: ['F', 'G']
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without importing any package?

Answer (score 7):

```py
output = {}

items = [[4, 'A'], [4, 'B'], [5, 'C'], [5, 'D'], [5, 'E'], [6, 'F'], [6, 'G']]

for number, letter in items:
    if number not in output:
        output[number] = []
    output[number].append(letter)


print('\n'.join(f'{number} : {letters}' for number, letters in output.items()))
```

**Output**

```
4 : ['A', 'B']
5 : ['C', 'D', 'E']
6 : ['F', 'G']
```

**Explanation**

- I use the name `items` rather than `list` so as to not conflict with the stdlib `list`.
- I unpack the number and letter into two variables whilst looping through the items.
- For each item, I check whether it already exists as a key in the output. If not, I instantiate an empty list.*
- I append the letter into its corresponding list.

* I would recommend using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this to simplify your code.

Comment: is there a way to do it without importing any other package?

Comment: @ShB I have altered the code to remove the import of `collections`. Note that this is part of the standard library so it doesn't require any additional library installations.

Comment: There is typo: it is `output = {}` and not `output = []`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution (but slow for big lists) that does not require any external package:

```py
res = {}
for k,v in items:
    res[k] = res.get(k, []) + [v]
print('\n'.join(f'{k} : {res[k]}' for k in res))
```

Comment: This is really inefficient as it unnecessarily instantiates two new lists and copies the main list for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dictionary method [**`setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) for this. It works like this:
If the key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert the key with a value of default(empty `list` in this case) and return default(`list`).

```
result = {}
for item in items:
    result.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item[1])

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{4: ['A', 'B'], 5: ['C', 'D', 'E'], 6: ['F', 'G']}
```